# BufferImage: How to certainly determine a pixel color

Tags: java, image

I have a bitmap encoded at PNG format. How to certainly determine where is black where is white?

```
            final int[] p = new int[1];
            int iter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); i++) {
                    pixels[iter] = image.getData().getPixel(i, j, p)[0];
                    iter++;
                }
            }
```

return me always 1 per pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
// Getting pixel color by position x=100 and y=40 
int clr=  image.getRGB(100,40); 
int  red   = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int  green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int  blue  =  clr & 0x000000ff;
```

red, green and blue will be the RGB values of pixel at x=100 and y=40

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you image is encoded, the pixels are packed into the one  integer, Sa for instance BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR the high byte is alpha, followed by blue, green then red.